# How to create php array from MySQL column?

Tags: php, mysql, row

I have such table:

```
id | name                                 | link
---+--------------------------------------+---------------
1  |SAsasasdsa,Главная страница,Main page | addsad
```

I want to get array like that:

```
$arr = array('az'=>'SAsasasdsa','ru'=>'Главная страница','en'=>'Main page');
```

Comment: so are you using PHP to access the database?

Comment: these index az, ru and en are constant or not?

Comment: where does it comes `'az'`,`'ru'` and `'en'` , from database??

Comment: @mathematical.coffee yes of course.

Comment: @GauravVashishtha is a language implementation using CSV in database

Comment: If you store the string using json, you would be able to pull it out and decode it to a usable associative array.  This practice can be frowned up though! (`json_encode($array);` and `json_decode($row['name']);`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRY

```
$qry = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table');
//for multiple rows
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)) { $input[] = $row['name'] }
$key = array('az', 'ru', 'en');
foreach($input as $val) { 
  $output[] = array_combine($key,explode(',',$val));
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($output);
```

Reference

[`array_combine`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Comment: I tried your version but got error. before left delimeter is there while?

Comment: Warning: array_combine() [function.array-combine]: Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in test.php on line 8

Comment: finally it worked. but i have more than 1 row. you said but could you show example pls??